# javadoc seems to treat class name in .aj file as package name

Tags: javadoc, aspectj

I'm generating Javadoc for a library that is mainly plain Java, but because one class is generated and I need to add a method to that class (and I can't use inheritance for this), I've created an AspectJ file for it.  Naturally, I have to define the new method by prefixing it with the class that it belongs to.

Now Javadoc is aborting with the error message:

```
javadoc: error - Illegal package name: "C:\company\project\library\trunk\library\src\main\java\com\company\project\library\classname_extensionname.aj"
```

(names substituted to protect the innocent)
Inside the .aj file I have:

```
package com.company.project.library;

import com.company.project.library.classname;

public aspect classname_extensionname {
   // various static final variables
   // various static methods to help the method I'm publicising
   public String classname.toString() {
      StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
      buffer.append( /* various bits and pieces */ );
      return buffer.toString();
   }
}
```

(original question erroneously had ".aj" at the end of the line beginning "public aspect")

So what is wrong with that?

I'm using jdk 1.7_09 within Spring Tool Suite 3.1.0.RELEASE (Eclipse)

P.S. I tried using ajdoc, but that couldn't resolve org.junit, org.slf4j or org.apache.xxx.

Comment: Is your aspect really named `classname_extensionname.aj` or was that a copy/paste error? Looks really weird.

Comment: Well, I didn't want to call it classname.aj in case I wanted to add some other aspects.  Let's call it classname_aspectname.aj.  In practice the classname was TdkQoS and the aspectname was Strings.

Comment: You did not get my point. I was referring to the aspect name in the code, not the file name. Why does the aspect name have ".aj" at the end?

Comment: Oops. Please forgive the error in copying and pasting.

Answer (score 0):

I'd get rid of the underscore in the filename, call your aspect "ClassnameAdvice" and the .aj file as ClassnameAdvice.aj.  Alternately, you may have just needed to get rid of the ".aj" in your aspect name inside the .aj file.

Comment: I've tried removing the underscore and that doesn't work.      The ".aj" within the file was an error in transcribing - it's not there.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to exclude .aj files from the javadoc plugin in maven.  Many of the tooling products that work on source code, dont work with aspects yet (pmd, checkstyle, findbugs etc).

Comment: There's a clue that I really have got a problem in http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-136934.html#exclude - there it suggests I should just list all the files I want to document.  Actually there's quite a few.